# When Using AngularJS Extend to Apply Resolve HTTP get Fails

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am attempting to dynamically attach a resolve parameter to all of my defined routes using this code:

```
    // attach resolve to each route programatically
    var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when;

    $routeProvider.when = function(path, route) {

        if (path !== '/login') {
            route.resolve || (route.resolve = {});
            angular.extend(route.resolve, {
                authorize: function($http) {
                    console.log("authorize test");
                    return $http.get('/svc/authorize/view?urlPath=' + path)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            var data = response.data;
                            if (response.data.result === 'NOT_AUTHORIZED') {
                                throw "NOT_AUTHORIZED";
                            }

                            return data;
                        });
                }
            });

            return originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, when accessing routes, the `$http.get()` never fires. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Instead of monkey patching `$routeProvider`, it would be wiser to write a custom provider that extends `$routeProvider`. Monkey patching is loading order dependent.

Comment: Another approach is to replace ngRoute with UI-Router 1.X and implement a [global transition hook](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on a timeline and not able to change out libraries we are using, and I'm learning AngularJS as I go.

Comment: If you're on a timeline, why are you wasting time with Stackoverflow and monkey patches?

Comment: Because I have a large number of routes already defined that need the resolve attached to them, and future plans to move to Angular (n) after this gets to production, when we can redesign our routes.